# How to access Google Cloud SQL from domain's user account via google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

Admin of a domain created a Google Cloud SQL instance....Now a user of that domain wants to access Google Cloud SQL via google Apps Script, but he is not able to access....
When I run this code from admin account it works :

var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://"+instance_name+"/"+database_name,"root","");

but when i run this code from a domain user then it gives this error :

Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Does that user have access to the database ? [see doc here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access_control).   Or you can also provide userName and password [as advanced arguments in parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_jdbc)

Comment: I have already passed username and password in jdbc query.
one solution is that to add user into project team member...I have already seen that and after adding into project,it works properly....But i want to know whether there is another solution of this problem or not ?

Comment: I think you should re-formulate your question more clearly : your question would be : *Is there a way to programmatically manage sharing properties of a Google Cloud SQL database ?*

Comment: I just want to access database from domain user account....Its not necessary that i provide access to users pragmatically or manually......But if you know any way then just let me know..

Comment: @Rishi - you are right in that the "effective user" has to be a member of the Console Project. See the "Authorization" section towards the bottom of this page - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc

Comment: I did the following in the api console with a google account of team member of the project. Created and granted all to a user:  `CREATE SCHEMA mydb;` and `GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO  'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` Then in the apps script I try to connect as follows  `Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://lagaroo.com.br:lagarooid:lobo/mysql","newuser","password")`
Still though I get the same error message, where as with "root" I do connect.